# is it possible to send push notification using shared hosting service?

Tags: iphone, shared-hosting, apple-push-notifications

i want to know that can i use shared hosting service for push notification or i need some another? which one is best for push notification please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the capabilities allowed by the shared hosting service.

You will need a site that allows you to run code (perl, python, ruby, php, etc) and database access will probably be needed for most applications.  I have notifications working on a shared hosting site that I have shell access to and can run scripts along with SQLite and MySQL.  I pay $25/mo for my service.

Comment: would like to know the service provider @CocoaFu

Comment: My understanding is Can we use a service like http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/index.html or https://github.com/facebook/scribe which are elegant push technology. Correct/clarify me if i am wrong.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know about those service, the service I use allows me shell access and full scripting access--I wrote all my code from scratch in python.